# Excerpt below image php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to display one line of excerpt from posts beneath the images at the bottom of this website: http://www.wha2wear.com/ This is the php function used to get the images and the excerpt:

```
<div class="blog">
<h2><span>Sneak peak</span></h2>
<ul>
<?php query_posts('orderby=comment_count&posts_per_page=6'); if ( have_posts() ):      

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<li>
<h3 class="short_title"><a title="Post: <?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php   

the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo ShortTitle(get_the_title()); ?> </a></h3>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php getImage('1'); ?></a>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '6');
    echo '...</a>';
    echo '</li>'; ?></a>


<?php endwhile; ?></li>
<?php else : ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts were found.</p>

</ul>
</div>
```

The problem is on two of the photos the excerpt is showing next to the photo instead if beneath it...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<br/>` tag:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php getImage('1'); ?></a>

<br/>


<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '6');
```

Comment: Thank you but I've already tried that with no luck..it looks like the image is taking the alignment directly from the post where the image is aligned to the left and the other one to the right <img alt="grow hair" src="http://www.wha2wear.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/grow-hair.jpg" width="394" height="403" align="right" />

Answer (score 0):

You need to put them into DIVs and use CSS to correctly assign width so they stack correctly.

Starting with each 'post' in each div then inside that add the content.

```
<div class="individual_post">
    <div class="post_title">
    <h3 class="short_title"><a title="Post: <?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php   
    the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo ShortTitle(get_the_title()); ?> </a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="post_image">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php getImage('1'); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="post_text">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '6');
    echo '...</a>';
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use your css to make the width of each section the same so they stack (even though they should stack by default anyway...)

Hope this helps.

Comment: tried that too with no luck :( thanks

Comment: Paste me your code and link me your site. It seems that you must have some CSS clashing with what I've written as this is right.